# Django can i reverse a parameterized url without passing any arguments?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

```
app_name = 'app_name'
path('url/<uuid:uuid>',someview.as_view(),name='somename')

def get_url():
   return reverse('app_name:somename',args=None)
```

I want get_url to return 'url/'
Is it possible?

If not, can i somehow get the partial url without the param like **'url/**'?

Comment: No, you can't. The idea is that you should fill in the parameters. It would also be an invalid URL. The slashes in the path are not really "compartments" in the sense that people interpret these as compartments, but it is just a simple slash.

Comment: Both forward and reverse lookup of the URL `url/` would require an additional route. It could lead to the same view if a [default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments) is defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple paths with the same name but with different parameters.

```
app_name = 'app_name'

urlpatterns = [
    path('url/', someview.as_view(), name='somename'),
    path('url/<str:foo>/', someview.as_view(), name='somename'),
]
```

When you use `reverse` the url pattern that matches the name and parameters that you pass will be returned

```
reverse('app_name:somename', kwargs={'foo': 'bar'})  # /url/bar/
reverse('app_name:somename')  # /url/
```

Comment: Would this be a good practice? Including both urls would enable a user to hit either of these and what if it is an update view? Wouldn't it result in a crash?

Comment: @Ahsan it makes sense if the view accepts arguments that are not required

Comment: I always forget to add `app_name` to `reverse` and end up with "Reverse not found".

Answer (score 0):

You could use [re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#re-path):

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
   re_path('url/(?P<some_id>[0-9]*)$', some_view, name='someview-name'),
]
```

This way, `url/` is valid, `url/12` is valid, but `url/foobar` is not.

Note that when you `return reverse('app_name:somename',args=None)`, None is interpreted as a string, so it's better to do `return reverse('app_name:somename',args='')`.
Anyway, `re_path('url/(?P<some_id>[0-9]*|None)$'` also works.